# Visual Studio web testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I come from a world of PHP (Laravel) and have faced no issues with testing the API or webpage like this before. Every time I would make a change I'd simply refresh the page, and it would show me the result of my changed actions.

This does not seem to be the case with my new experience with VS as it seems I have to run <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> every time I make a simple change to the program. To make things even more annoying, it is always opening a new tab with each program run.

Is this simply the way "VS is", or am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something. Make sure Browser Link is on.

Comment: It is on by default

Comment: VS Code has better support for this if you are developing a .net Core project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with VS. PHP is a script language, it doesn't get compiled before running like c# does. You have to do a build of the project in order for the DLLs to be up-to-date

Comment: So there is no way around it I presume? :)

Comment: No there isn't :) but you can simplify it if you don't need debugging. You could host it on your IIS and just build the solution and refresh the browser tab.

Comment: Yes, this works, by just saving the project and refreshing, no need for F5 again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you're using IIS express and ASP.NET.

Right click on Project and then choose View in Browser.

You'll need to do a build though if you make any changes to the C# but not if making changes to CSS/Javascript (excluding things like SASS etc)